# Why does H₂Se have a bigger Ka2 than H₂Te

Tags: acid-base

Why does $\ce{H2Se}$ have a bigger $K_\text{a2}$ than both $\ce{H2S}$ and $\ce{H2Te}$?

Comment: What do you mean with "$Ka_2$"?

Comment: @Philipp $K_{a2}$ refers to the second dissociation constant i.e. the equilibrium constant of $\ce {HA^{-}<=> H+ + A^{2-}}$

Comment: Would you mind to provide the data and the source?

Answer (score 4):

The following data are from the *Rubber Book* (CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics), 89th edition, 2009, p 8-40.

\begin{array}{lll}
\mathrm{acid} & \mathrm{pK_{a1}} & \mathrm{pK_{a2}} \\
\hline
\ce{H2S} & 7.05 & 19\\ 
\ce{H2Se} & 3.89& 11\\
\ce{H2Te} & 2.6 & 11\\
\end{array}

Note that $\mathrm{pK_{a1}}$ of $\ce{H2Te}$ was determined at 18 °C, all other data at 25 °C