# Is RS- more basic than RO-?

Tags: acid-base, stability

The basic strength is determined by the ability of an ion or molecule to accept a proton. How do I know whether RSH is more stable than ROH?
(R is an alkyl group)

Comment: [My recent answer to this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27746) is quite relevant, with the small difference that one hydrogen gets swapped for an alkyl group. Just remember that stronger acids create weaker conjugate bases.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. Thiols are more acidic than alcohols so the conjugate base of a thiol is a weaker base than the alcohol conjugate base.

Comment: **It isn't.** ${}$

Comment: It may also be helpful to point out that the strength of a base is only as you define it for a Brønsted-Lowry base.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/147841/why-is-negative-charge-more-stable-on-sulphur-than-on-oxygen/147846#147846

Answer (score 5):

**RobChem** has already pointed out in his comment that your assumption is not quite correct.

Take a look at $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values for $\ce{ROH}$ and $\ce{RSH}$ in water from the *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics* and/or other online sources, such as [this](http://www.diederich.chem.ethz.ch/teach/pKa_Table.pdf) or [that](http://research.chem.psu.edu/brpgroup/pKa_compilation.pdf).

\begin{array}{lrr}
\mathbf{R} & {\ce{\mathbf{OH}}} &\ce{\mathbf{SH}}\\
\hline
\ce{H} & 15.7 &7.0\\
\ce{Et} & 15.9 & 10.6\\
\ce{(H3C)3C} & 18.0 & 11.7\\
\ce{C6H5} & 9.9 & 6.6\\
\end{array}

In all the cases above, the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value for $\ce{RSH}$ is smaller than that of $\ce{ROH}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{RSH}$ is a better acid than $\ce{ROH}$ (as the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{RSH}$ is lower than the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{ROH}$, shown in a previous answer). This means that $\ce{RSH}$ dissociates into $\ce{RS-}$ and $\ce{H+}$ more, *i.e.* the equilibrium below lies more to the right.

$\ce{RSH + H2O <=> RS- + H3O+}$

To compare between $\ce{ROH}$ and $\ce{RSH}$, we must look at the difference, which is the atom: $\ce{S}$ or $\ce{O}$. As they are in the same group, we look at their polarisability. As $\ce{S}$ is larger and hence more polarisable, it means that the negative electron is more stable in $\ce{RS-}$ than in $\ce{RO-}$. Hence the conjugate base, $\ce{RS-}$ is more stable than $\ce{RO-}$, and so $\ce{RSH}$ is a stronger acid than $\ce{ROH}$.

Conversely, $\ce{RS-}$ is a worse base than $\ce{RO-}$.