# Why methanol is more acidic than water

Tags: organic-chemistry

All alcohols are less acidic than water except methanol. Methyl group exhibits positive inductive effect. So water should be more acidic than water. But according to experimental evidence it is not so. Can someone explain the reason for this.

Comment: Your question has been asked previously, and has an answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42535/why-is-methanol-more-acidic-than-water).  For future reference, you're able to search chem.SE using the 'search Q&A' bar at the top of the page, or equally the linked question appears on google if you search for "why is methanol more acidic than water".

Comment: @NotEvans. the answer there is wrong. Water has a pKa of 14.0 (not 15.7 like Evans pKa table shows. https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Fundamentals/What_is_the_pKa_of_water%3F 
http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00623

Comment: @DSVA. Irrespective, the question is a direct duplicate and should be closed as such, you could always answer the original question, correcting the 'wrong' data

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't knew that the question was asked before. Please provide me with the answer.